# Testing if two strings are equal is giving odd results

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two lists in javascript. If something exists in ListA that isn't in ListB - I want to push it up to ListB. If it DOES exist, I don't want to do anything. The items in the lists are strings.

When I check if one string is equal to the other, I get really odd results. here is my JS:

```
function assignColor() {
    var test = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth", "SomeoneElse", "AnotherSomeone"]
    var list_existing = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth"];
    length_of_existing = list_existing.length;

    i=0;
    while ( i < test.length ) {
        var person_in_list = test[i]

        for ( var j=0; j <= parseInt(length_of_existing); j++) {

            if ( person_in_list === list_existing[j]) {
                console.log("equal");
            }
            else {
                console.log("not equal");
                list_existing.push(person_in_list);
            }
        }
    ++i;
    }
    console.log(list_existing);
}
```

The output I get for list_existing is as follows:

> ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth", "JackBean", "JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth"]

It's probably frustratingly simple. But I've tried a few different combinations to compare the two strings successfully.... unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that very easy using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which holds unique values by definition - so all you have to do is to concat() the both arrays, create a new Set with them, and you got your result:

```js
var test = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth", "SomeoneElse", "AnotherSomeone"]
var list_existing = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth"];

let set = new Set(list_existing.concat(test));
let result = [...set];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem reside in your `if/else` condition

Basiclly, when your found an equality, you should not continue to iterate on your `list_existing` you should stop and continue the while loop.

So my idea is to modify `for ( var j=0; j <= parseInt(length_of_existing); j++)`

to

```
for ( var j=0; j <= parseInt(length_of_existing) && notFound; j++)
```

and notFound is initialized at true and become false when an equality is found.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so what you are doing is checking each element against every other element. This means that when Jack is compared to Jack, nothing happens, but then you compare Jack to MrX, it thinks Jack needs to be added.

Solve this problem by looking at the whole array instead of individual elements.

```
function assignColor() {
    var test = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth", "SomeoneElse", "AnotherSomeone"]
    var list_existing = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth"];
    length_of_existing = list_existing.length;

    i=0;
    while ( i < test.length ) {
        var person_in_list = test[i]

        if (list_existing.indexOf(test[i]) === -1) { //not found
            list_existing.push(test[i]); //add the missing element
        }
    ++i;
    }
    console.log(list_existing);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsuh18gL/1/)

`array.indexOf` looks to see if the value already exists and returns the index if it does. You need to be careful with this since you can get `0` as a valid result (index 0 in an array is the first one as you know). `array.indexOf` solves this by using `-1` as `false`/not-found. This is why I had to specify in the if statement instead of just booleanizing the result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the second statement of your for loop definition: it says `j <= parseInt(length_of_existing)` but it should say `j < parseInt(length_of_existing)`, since if you use <=, the loop will run one extra time. During that extra time, the element in the current index (4), will be undefined, therefore, the if statement below will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

what about doing something like this ?

```
function assignColor() {
    var test = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth", "SomeoneElse", "AnotherSomeone"]
    var list_existing = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth"];


    test.forEach(item => {
        if(!~list_existing.indexOf(item)){
            list_existing.push(item);
        }
    });
    console.log(list_existing);
}

assignColor();
```

Just loop the first array and check if item exists in the second array with a simple "indexOf" :)

EDIT : baao has a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This would be far simpler:

```
var test = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var list_existing = ['b', 'd'];

test.forEach(function(el) {
  if (list_existing.indexOf(el) === -1) {
      list_existing.push(el);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easly with includes function

```
function assignColor()
{

var a = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth", "SomeoneElse", "AnotherSomeone"];
var b = ["JackBean", "MrX", "SuperMan", "BobHemsworth"];

             for(var j=0; j < a.length; j++) {

            if( b.includes(a[j])) alert("contain")  

            else b.push(a[j]);

    }
console.log(b)
}
```